# Compiling Qt5: Adding a postfix to the Qt libs and dlls (-qtlibinfix)

Tags: qt, qt5, configure

I am in the process of upgrading from Qt4 to Qt5.

When I compiled the Qt4 sources I used to configure like this:

```
configure –qtlibinfix _64_
```

We did this for the x64 build so that the resulting Qt dlls would be renamed QtCore_64_.dll etc...
We are supporting both 64 and 32 bit builds and this made it a lot easier for us.

However, now with Qt5 it seems the -qtlibinfix option is gone. Is there an equivalent? Or another way a similar thing can be accomplished.

I have been scouring the Qt doc, and I have not found anything yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also porting an app from Qt4 to Qt5.  `-qtlibinfix` works for me as expected on Windows, building Qt 5.4.0.